# What should a person who has not prayed salah for majority of his life do?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

if a person who is 45 and above years of age and has not prayed a single day in his life, is he required to do qaza for all of his missed prayer? or is there something else he/she can do?
what can the person do so that Allah forgive such a person?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. To answer this we need input as answers of the following questions: why did this person not pray? Due to ignorance? Due to laziness? or due to refusal to pray? Did this person always consider prayer as a duty?...

Answer (score -1):

One may **repent sincerely** to Allah and manage to keep up nafl prayers.

If the one who did not pray untill he was old Deliberately untill the time for prayer was over, he cannot makeup his skipped prayers, he may need to repent and do good deeds, and follow the prayers he skipped with nafl prayers.

If the person did not pray because he forgot, there is no sin on him but he will need to make up the prayer.

For Allah to forgive a person, the person may need to repent sincerely. You can check the conditions of a sincere repentance.